# Deleting node from singly linked list

Tags: linked-list

If your goal is to write a function to delete a node in a singly linked list, and you are only given access to the node you want to delete (not given head), Why doesn't my solution work?

My solution:

```
public void deleteNode(Node n) {
    n = n.next;
}
```

Book's solution:

```
public void deleteNode(Node n) {
    n.data = n.next.data;
    n.next = n.next.next;
}
```

It seems to me that simply assigning n to n.next takes care of assigning the data and pointer in one line.

Comment: There's an inherent weakness in the book's solution. It's impossible to track the 'last' element because removing the last element would require a full traversal to reset the reference to the 'last' element. So, either you track a reference to the last element and do a full list traversal every time the last element is removed or you don't track the last element and do a full traversal every time an element is added to the end of the list. Eek.

Comment: Yeah this actually wasn't the entirety of the book's solution. I just posted the portion I had a question about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy mistake to make before you get a good mental model of how the manipulation of linked lists work.  The `deleteNode` is given a reference to the node you want to delete.  It stores this reference in the variable `n` which is set up **only** for the use of the `deleteNode` code.  In your solution, `deleteNode` changes the value of `n` to point to the next node in the list, but this only affects `n` which is discarded once execution reached the end of `deleteNode`.  The linked list still exists exactly as it did before `deleteNode` was executed.  Put another way, the node that precedes the node you want to delete still points to the same node that it did when you entered `deleteNode`, and the node that was supposed to be deleted still points to the next in the line.  Changing `n` had no effect.

The book's solution, however, does change things up a bit.  After it runs, the node that is supposed to be deleted now contains the data and next pointer from what used to be the next node down.  This affectively "shifts" the contents of the next node up one.

Comment: but is that not also true for the book's solution?

Comment: Added a bit more detail to hopefully help.  With linked lists it often helps to draw things out.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: so the book's solution changes `n.data` in the reference `n` AND the actual node?

Comment: Yes - `n` is a *reference* to a real underlying `Node` object.  When you assign to `n` you're merely changing the reference. However, when you assign to `n.data` or `n.next` you're modifying a field on the actual object.

Answer (score 1):

All nodes are somewhere in the memory, and each node knows where to find the next node
(independent of variables in the code, ie. no "n" or something like that).
Additionally, there can be one or more variables per node which are "pointing"
to that node in memory, The problem in your method is, you´re only
changing the target of your vriable n, but not the nodes itself.

If you have 4 nodes with values A,B,C,D and want to delete B, your variable n points to B.
After the assignment in your method, n would point to C,
but the 4 nodes itself would be unchanged.
The books solution does change the value and next of B itself...